# Accessing specific elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am creating a program to add guests to a party. The maximum number of guests is set at 3. My program outputs the 3 guests correctly.

However, how do I access and print out the elements that did not make the list?

As you can see in my Party2Driver, I called my "addGuest" method 5 times. The program correctly added the first 3 names to the list since I set the maxGuests to 3. But how do I output the last two names that weren't added to the list?

I want it to read something like "blank and blank" weren't added to the list because the guest list is full.

Every time I try to access those ArrrayList elements with the "get method" it throws an OutOutBoundException.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Party2Driver
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {

      Party2 party = new Party2(3, "David Beckham");
      party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
      party.addGuest("Zinedine Zidane");
      party.addGuest("Roberto Baggio");
      party.addGuest("Johan Cruyff");
      party.addGuest("Diego Maradona");
      party.printParty();

    } // end main

}//end Party2Driver
```

Here is the Party 2 Class with my methods:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Party2
{
    // instance variables that will hold your data
    // private indicates they belong to this class exclusively
    private int maxGuests;
    private String host;
    private ArrayList<String> guests;

    //Constructor
    public Party2(int maxGuests, String host)
    {
        System.out.println("Maximum number of guests: " + maxGuests + ".  Guest list for " + host + "'s party. \n");
        this.guests = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.maxGuests = maxGuests;
        this.host = host;
    }

    //getter
    // define type of data to be returned
    public String getHost()
    {
        System.out.println("Setting host to: " + host);
        return host;
    }

    //setter
    // setters have type void b/c they return nothing
    public void setHost(String host)
    {
        System.out.println("Setting host to: " + host);
        this.host = host;
    }

    //*************************************
    //Method to add to guest list
    public void addGuest(String guest)
    {

        if (guests.size() < maxGuests)
        {
            System.out.println("Guest: " + guest + "\n");
            this.guests.add(guest);
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("     Guest cannot be added. Guest list is full. \n");
        }//end if

    }//end method

    //*************************************
    //Method to print party
    public void printParty()
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************************\n");
        System.out.println("Guest list for " +
        this.host + "'s party is: \n\n" +
        this.guests + ".\n");

    } // end Print Party method

    }//end class party
```

Comment: Define _"get method"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add extraGuest field:

```
private ArrayList<String> extraGuest;
```

In addGuest(guest) method's else block add extraGuest.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Party2
{
 // instance variables that will hold your data
 // private indicates they belong to this class exclusively
 private int maxGuests;
 private String host;
 private ArrayList<String> guests;
 private ArrayList<String> extraGuest;

 //Constructor
 public Party2(int maxGuests, String host)
 {
    System.out.println("Maximum number of guests: " + maxGuests + ".  Guest list for " + host + "'s party. \n");
    this.guests = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.extraGuest = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.maxGuests = maxGuests;
    this.host = host;
 }

 //getter
 // define type of data to be returned
 public String getHost()
 {
    System.out.println("Setting host to: " + host);
    return host;
 }

 //setter
 // setters have type void b/c they return nothing
 public void setHost(String host)
 {
    System.out.println("Setting host to: " + host);
    this.host = host;
 }

 //*************************************
 //Method to add to guest list
 public void addGuest(String guest)
 {

    if (guests.size() < maxGuests)
    {
        System.out.println("Guest: " + guest + "\n");
        this.guests.add(guest);
    }

    else
    {
        extraGuest.add(guest);
        System.out.println("     Guest cannot be added. Guest list is full. \n");
    }//end if

 }//end method

 //*************************************
 //Method to print party
 public void printParty()
 {
      System.out.println("****************************************************\n");
    System.out.println("Guest list for " +
    this.host + "'s party is: \n\n" +
    this.guests + ".\n");

    System.out.println(extraGuest+"weren't added to the list because the guest list is full");

 } // end Print Party method

}//end class party
```

Comment: This worked. Now that I did this, it made me realize that I wasn't thinking of the ArrayList in the wrong terms. I was trying to make the "guests" ArrayList do more than what it was supposed to. The "extraGuest" definitely should've have had a seperate list. Hindsight always makes sense when you're a beginner and still learning!

Answer (score 3):

Create a second ArrayList called something like `rejectedGuests`, and whenever a guest is rejected, add them to that list. Then put a getter method to retrieve the list. From there it's just a simple String.format() call, and a println() statement.